# ArrayList.size() showing zero every time. Actually im trying to Filter the Data using the data stored on the ArrayList

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview

ArrayList.size() showing zero every time. Actually im trying to Filter the Data using the data stored on the ArrayList

This is my HomeFragment.Java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private static final String TAG_check="check";
    public RecyclerView  recyclerView;
    SearchView realsv;

    private AlbumsAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Album> albumList;
    private ArrayList<Album> test;
    private Album album;
    public ImageView imga;
    public CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;

    public AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        realsv=(SearchView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.realsv);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rcv);
        //test.addAll(albumList);
        //test.clear();
        realsv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
         }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.i("YES","FIRST STEP"+albumList.size());
            newText=newText.toLowerCase();

            for(Album al: albumList)
            {

                String title = al.getName().toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<Album> test = new ArrayList<>();
                Log.i("CHEK",title);
                if(title.contains(newText)){
                    Log.i("CHEK ok",title+"ok");
                    test.add(al);
                }
            }
            adapter.setFilter(test);
           // adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
         }
        });
        initViews();
        return rootView;
    }

     private void initViews(){
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("Fetching Data...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();





        albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), albumList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        loadJSON();
    }

    private void loadJSON(){
        try{

            Client Client = new Client();
            //this is where it all changes
            Hindi apiService = Client.getClient().create(Hindi.class);
            Call<AlbumsResponse> call = apiService.getAlbums();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<AlbumsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AlbumsResponse> call, Response<AlbumsResponse> response) {
                    ArrayList<Album> items = response.body().getAlbums();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), items));
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                    pd.hide();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AlbumsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Fetching Data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pd.hide();

                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
           // Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is My adapter Class for Recyclerview

```
public class AlbumsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Album> albumList;
    //private List<Album> newList;

    public AlbumsAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Album> albuList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.albumList = albuList;
       // this.newList=albuList;
    }

    @Override
    public AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.album_card, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(albumList.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.count.setText(albumList.get(i).getLang());

        //load album cover using picasso
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(albumList.get(i).getThumbnail())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.load)
                .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
    }

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<Album> nn){
        albumList= new ArrayList<Album>();
        for (Album al:nn){
            albumList.add(al);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    /**
     * Click listener for popup menu items
     */
    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_play_next:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return albumList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
           // overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);

            //on item click
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        Album clickedDataItem = albumList.get(pos);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Det.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", albumList.get(pos).getName());
                        intent.putExtra("lang", albumList.get(pos).getLang());
                        intent.putExtra("thumbnail", albumList.get(pos).getThumbnail());
                        intent.putExtra("scrn",albumList.get(pos).getScrn());
                        intent.putExtra("ourl",albumList.get(pos).getOurl());
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                       // Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " + clickedDataItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`

This is Model Class Album.java

```
public class Album {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("lang")
    @Expose
    private String lang;
    @SerializedName("thumbnail")
    @Expose
    private String thumbnail;
    @SerializedName("scrn")
    @Expose
    private String scrn;
    @SerializedName("ourl")
    @Expose
    private String ourl;

    public Album() {
    }

    public Album(String name, String lang, String thumbnail, String scrn, 
    String ourl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.scrn=scrn;
        this.ourl=ourl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getScrn() {
        return scrn;
    }

    public void setScrn(String scrn) {
        this.scrn = scrn;
    }

    public String getOurl() {
        return ourl;
    }

    public void setOurl(String ourl) {
        this.ourl = ourl;
    }
}
```

This is the AlbumResponse.java

```
public class AlbumsResponse {

    @SerializedName("Album")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Album> albums;

    public ArrayList<Album> getAlbums(){
        return albums;
    }
    public void setAlbums(ArrayList<Album>albums){
        this.albums = albums;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your adaptur with albumlist or where are you populating your Albumlist in your homefragment? You are applying filter to the albumlist which doesn't seem to have values as its not populated anywhere yet

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? You just put a title and code but you have to specify which class or which line at least?

Comment: @kapsym I Populated the ArrayList using the json. I vl update the code right now. plz have a look

Comment: @Raghavendra Plz have a look now. The ArrayList is getting Populoated with no issues. The problem is that Search functionality is not working

Comment: The code i can see is albumList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), albumList); 
This means your adapter is initialized with an empty array. where did you get the albumList from your json response?

Comment: @kapsym FROM the LoadJson() method in Homefrgament class

Comment: Ok so in your LoadJson method, you populate a new array called items and then populate your adapter with it. So in your adapter your albumList gets populated which is fine. But then in your OnQueryTextChanged method you check for your query string in albumList array, which you have declared in your Home fragment but never initialized. So hence no filter results. assign your items to albumlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in your LoadJson method, you populate a new array called items and then populate your adapter with it. So in your adapter your albumList gets populated which is fine. But then in your OnQueryTextChanged method you check for your query string in albumList array, which you have declared in your Home fragment but never initialized. So hence no filter results. assign your items to albumlist and it will work

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: im getting this on    line 75 of AlbumAdapter after implementing what you have said

Comment: change ArrayList<Album> test = new ArrayList<>(); to  test = new ArrayList<>(); in you onquerytextchanged method. since test is declared as member of class, assign it to same test array

Comment: right now you are creating another test array which is local variable and assigning there hence your global array is empty so adapter.setfilter is called on global..

Comment: or bring this line outside for loop. both will work..
ArrayList<Album> test = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @ user3577975 Let me know if you face issues.

Comment: Yeah i brought the test variable out of the loop. Now the Filter logic is working Perfectly. But the notifyDatasetChanged Method is not working in adapter class

Comment: What do you mean by notifyDatasetChanged not working? Is your list not getting filtered? Your view is not updating?

Comment: I made it to work by using two lines in onQuerytextchange

Comment: recyclerView.setAdapter(new AlbumsAdapter(getActivity(), test));
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

Answer (score 0):

In your loadJson() method, in onResponse you are creating a new ArrayList to get all albums and not setting that to your global variable albumList.
So you should do this,

```
ArrayList<Album> items = response.body().getAlbums();
albumList.addAll(items);
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: @user3577975 use the above method, not my previous first one.  I think it was happening because same list was passed to adapter and it was re-initialized and hence changing the global one.

Comment: Now my filtering logic is working fine. Now the problem is that my view is not getting updated